# Call procedure passing parameters inside Syncronize Method from TTask PPL

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

Using PPL - TTask in delphi to update UI form objects we need to use "Synchronize" method. However, in some situations, I would like to call a method by passing it parameters, for the purpose of code reuse.

So I would like to clarify, if the implementation of the method synchronize as below would generate some problem and would no longer be considered thread safe?

```
      TThread.Synchronize(nil,
      procedure
      begin


        //-- Method receiving two parameters: boolean and string

        UpdateUIControls(taskSuccess, taskMessage);


      end);




procedure TForm.UpdateUIControls(taskSuccess: boolean; taskMessage: string)
begin

   LblTaskMessage.Caption  :=  taskMessage;

   if not taskSuccess then
   //Do something

end;
```

Comment: Use variable capture

Comment: The call to Synchronize is blocking, so you will most likely have no thread issues with these parameters - assuming they are local to the procedure calling Synchronize. Things would be different when you were calling Queue, although that might be more what you want in this case.

Comment: Sorry David Heffernan, I did not understand how I can do this.

Comment: @Marcoscdoni, if the parameters are not local as said in a comment by Uwe, you can capture the values of the parameters in a new frame. Example: `function Update(taskSuccess : Boolean; taskMessage : String) : TThreadProcedure; begin Result := procedure begin UpdateUIControls(taskSuccess,taskMessage) end; end;` and call: `TThread.Synchronize(nil,Update(taskSuccess,taskMessage));`